# JNDI Error on JSF 2.0 Migration

Tags: jsf-2, jndi, websphere-8, myfaces, trinidad

We are migrating our application from JSF (MyFaces, Trinidad) 1.2 to JSF (MyFaces, Trinidad) 2.0. I have done the all basic changes like updating the XMLNS for Faces-Config, updating the Web.xml to support 3.0, removed Facelets, el-api, el-ri Jars.

When I set the `classloaderMode` to `PARENT_LAST` in Websphere 8.5.5 for picking our MyFaces & Trinidad jar, I'm getting the below error.

`A java: URL name was used, but Naming was not configured to handle java: URL names. The likely cause is a user in error attempting to specify a java: URL name in a non-J2EE client or server environment. Throwing ConfigurationException`

But I'm **NOT** getting the same exception when I set the `classloaderMode` to `PARENT_FIRST`. How can I resolve this problem? Please help me.

Comment: Are you including WAS JARs in your application?  The error sounds like you have include WAS JNDI classes in your WAR, which when combined with PARENT_LAST causes the JDK JNDI to use those uninitialized classes rather than the ones included with WAS.  You should not repackage WAS JARs in your application.

Comment: @bkail Thank you. Yes. We are having 'com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar' in the war file. Will it impact??

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  You should never include WAS JARs in your application.

Comment: @bkail Thanks a lot. Now it's working fine

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sounds like you have include WAS JNDI classes in your WAR, which when combined with PARENT_LAST causes the JDK JNDI to use those uninitialized classes rather than the ones included with WAS. You should not repackage WAS JARs in your application.